# Rails: how to create a form to create a new has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User and a Project models that are linked with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship (each users can be a part of several projects, and they can be the creator of several projects). I want to create a form to add a user to a project. The user would need to enter the username of another user to add him. How can I do that?

Here is what I've tried:

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :username, "Username" %>
    <%= f.text_field :users %>
    <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

Then in the controller I would do something like this:

```
def add_user
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
    user.projects << @project
    user.save
    redirect_to @project
  end
```

The issue is that the text field for the user does not do what I thought it would, it output the `@project.users` inspect (`#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_User:0x007fc3e98e8d70>`).

I've see the nested forms but I don't think it's appropriate as the user and the project are already created. I'm using rails 4.

Comment: Not clear, what is it doing that it not what you thought it would. PS unless you have a uniqueness contraint on username, you are asking for it by not selecting the user. Also given your question I would have expected two users. The user to be added and the one 'authorising'

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I've edited the question for the `users` field. Yes the username have a uniqueness constraint, and there are two users in the scenario. The user being a part of the project adds another one by entering his username.

Comment: What did you want the text_field you have :users to do? Show a list of users, or just be a text field they could enter a name in? Think your real problem is in the controller that shows the form.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson just an empty text field to enter a username. The controller just sets the `@project` variable and checks if the user is a part of the project

Answer (score 1):

The nested forms stuff isn't just for creating new records, you can use it to add to join models, too

I would look at [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

---

**Accepts Nested Attributes For**

I would personally try this:

```
 #app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
 def new
      @project = Project.new
      @project.projects_users.build
 end

 def create
      @project = Project.new(project_params)
      @project.save
 end

 def edit
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
     @project = Project.find(params[:id])
     @project.save
 end

 private
 def project_params
     params.require(:project).permit(:project, :params, projects_users_attributes: [:user_id])
 end

#app/models/project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects_users
end

#app/views/projects/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :projects_users %>
        <%= f.label :username, "User ID" %>
        <%= f.text_field :user_id %> #-> can change to <select> later
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Trying to make this works but no chance yet. This gives me the error `No association found for name `projects_users'` even though the table exist. Do I have to use a `has_many :through` relationship instead of the `has_and_belongs_to_many`?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the cocoon gem. It provides some nested form stuff that would be hard to solve with rails of the shelf functionality. I have used it recently to do something very similar (find or create on M2M relation)

https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon